# Bootstrap Nav Bar Links Border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put a border around one of my links in my bootstrap nav bar so that it looks like this image here. [image]

I am trying to simply put a border around the `<li>` element, but the boundaries of Bootstrap navbar `<li>` elements go up to the very top and bottom of the navbar, unlike in the picture. Here is what my efforts look like:

[image]

The CSS I am trying to use is just a simple border:

```
#nav-signup {
    border: 1px solid #ACOLOR;
}
```

I tried setting margins around the link, but this pushes the link out of line with the others. I also tried wrapping the SIGN UP button in a div, but that makes it lose a lot of the bootstrap properties.

Is there any easy way for me to put this border around the SIGN UP link without having to fight bootstrap?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the text in span and add border to it thanks.